# iPhone often freezes nowadays

Tags: iphone, ios, performance

Is there a reason why nowadays, even in warm conditions, my iPhone freezes and restarts?

By this I mean it freezes for a while and then restarts into a black screen for 10-20 secs followed by the Apple logo and then the Home screen. This can happen when taking pictures, starting an app, or just opening a link in Safari. It seems to be a software problem and only started this year.

I've tried:

- Updating iOS to 11.2.2
- Taking it in for checking - the battery was replaced and they said the logic board was ok.

---

It's an iPhone 5s running iOS 11.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

The term "freezing" here should not be interpreted literally. Freezing simply means that the display stops updating, audio stops playing or similar (i.e. nothing is happening) - it doesn't have anything to do with hot or cold environments.

The behavior you're seeing sounds like a hardware defect.

You mentioned already having tried upgrading iOS. I would take a backup of the phone, and then do a complete restore of the iOS software - erasing all contents and settings on the phone. If it still freezes afterwards, it is most probably a hardware problem.

Comment: The iPhone 5s can be updated to iOS 12.5.1, which is probably much better than iOS 11.

Comment: At the time the question was asked, iOS 11.2.2 that he was running was actually the newest available version. 11.2.5 came out later that day. iOS 12.5.1 came much later in January 2021.